# Android emulator memory usage keeps increasing

Tags: linux, memory, android-emulator

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 64bit and latest eclipse.

One minute after I launch the emulator, the memory usage keeps increasing all the way to 1000 MB.  can anyone tell me why?

I limited the memory of emulator to 512mb, but didn't help.

Comment: Please do not tag question status on the title. If you found a solution, you can post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a memory leak, you should report it to the emulators buglist.  Leaks happen when a resource is not closed or deleted during a process's run time.